# how to create RDF with dependencies?

Tags: rdf

I'm struggling a bit with a camera ontology I am creating. It's pretty easy to generate single tripples but I'm wondering how I create a hierarchy. Basically I want to understand how I create RDF graphs where the subject becomes the object. I'm just starting with this so feel free to adjust / rewrite my terminology if it does not really match.

As example :

I have a class called optics, and I want to provide the maximum Aperture across a range of camera's. The value is however depending on a couple of paramaters, namely the lensPosition (Wide or Tele) and the sensor format (FullFrame or APS-C)

this are the potential results :

Camera A :

optics -- *withPosition* --> **Wide** -- *withFormat* --> **FullFrame** -- *hasMaxAperture* --> **1.8**

optics -- *withPosition* --> **Tele** -- *withFormat* --> **FullFrame** -- *hasMaxAperture* --> **4.0**

optics -- *withPosition* --> **Wide** -- *withFormat* --> **APS-C** -- *hasMaxAperture* --> **3.2**

optics -- *withPosition* --> **Tele** -- *withFormat* --> **APS-C** -- *hasMaxAperture* --> **6.0**

Camera B :

optics -- *withPosition* --> **Wide** -- *withFormat* --> **FullFrame** -- *hasMaxAperture* --> **4.0**

optics -- *withPosition* --> **Tele** -- *withFormat* --> **FullFrame** -- *hasMaxAperture* --> **8.0**

and so on...

How would I code this best using RDF/XML ?

Comment: Why are you specifically asking about RDF/XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you would want to model these relations as some kind of general rules, it'd be easier with Turtle (or N3, or NTriples, which are similar) than RDF/XML.

I think that your example is not a case of what you describe as

> the subject becomes the object

but rather a relationship between multiple parameters. With RDF one way you could model that is by grouping the parameters in a blank node

So here's some Turtle for Camera 1 (empty prefix assumed)

```
:optics :hasMaxAptertureDefinition [
  :withPosition :Wide ; 
  :withFormat :FullFrame;
  :hasMaxAperture 1.8
]
```

Would that work for you?

---

Equivalent RDF/XML would be something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rdf:RDF 
   xmlns:ns1="http://example/"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
>
   <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="ub428bL0C36">
      <ns1:withFormat rdf:resource="http://example/#FullFrame"/>
      <ns1:withPosition rdf:resource="http://example/#Wide"/>
      <ns1:hasMaxAperture rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#decimal">1.8</ns1:hasMaxAperture>
   </rdf:Description>
   <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example/#optics">
      <ns1:hasMaxAptertureDefinition rdf:nodeID="ub428bL0C36"/>
   </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Comment: Of course... I was indeed looking too far. Thanks! The reason I asked for rdf/xml is because I am working with an xml workflow, so it is more practical (but less clean indeed)

Comment: Glad I could help. In a sense it is the `the subject becomes the object` but it is the artificial joint of your relation sides - the blank node. It is evident in the RDF/XML snippet, where `ub428bL0C36` is object in one `rdf:Description` and subject in the other.